# Oracle order by undetermined

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to add pagination to a simple select query, like

```
select rownum rownum_,t.* from (select id,name from table) t
where rownum <=4
```

However the above query behaves differently when where condition is there and where condition is not there. But on removing the name column, the behaviour is consistent. Can anyone tell why?

I understand rownum is determined when query is run, what I'm not able to understand is that a where condition with rownum <=n , changes the order

Comment: Adding `rownum <=n` might modify the execution plan.

Answer (score 6):

You have to understand that `rownum` is a pseudo column.

The `rownum` column in your query indicates the order ( first record, second, third... )

Then the records order returned by

```
select id,name from table
```

is not guaranteed. In your request, the rownum associated to the first record will be always 1 despict the fact that the first record might be different every time.

In conclusion,  always use `ORDER BY` when you want a specific order.

Comment: For a known set of data, the behaviour is reproducible always. I just wanted to know how

Comment: As I wrote, the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5):

The table might have an index on `rownum` that it's using when you restrict with `rownum <= 4`. The order will then likely be defined by the index. This is the way it works in MySQL at least. If you want a specific ordering, always use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hmm, but without the character column, the issue does not appear

Comment: @Rnet, the solution is to always use `ORDER BY` when you want a specific ordering. There is no default ordering and the order may be influenced by whatever indexes are available, and/or by what order the data was inserted into the tables.

Comment: Yes, I was just pondering why the where condition was changing the result order i.e rownum <=4 different order rownum <= 10 different order ...

Comment: In Oracle, `rownum` is a pseudo-column that never has a value until the result set has been created, so it is not possible for there to be an index.

Answer (score 2):

When you exclude the `name` column from your query, the id's values are fetched from an index, not from table, so you get another order.

The second issue I bet is because the Optimizer uses parallel for getting more rows. Parallel threads allways return a 'mess order' because they retrieve data in parallel not sequential.
Try with a hint `/*+ NO_PARALLEL(table) */`